# How can I save a tab thumbnail to local storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to keep track of tab thumbnails for my google chrome extension, and would love for the ability to save them to my local storage.  Currently, I have something along the lines of:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(tab.windowId, function(thumb) {
     // other code here...
}
```

How can I save thumb to local storage?  Or should I not be saving thumb to local storage and instead reloading those thumbnails the next time the browser loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback of [`chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab) receives a data-URI (`data:image/png;base64,...` or `data:image/jpg;base64,...`). This is a plain string, which can be saved in `localStorage` as follows:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(tab.windowId, function(thumb) {
    // Example: Save by key URL
    localStorage.setItem(tab.url, thumb);
}); // <-- Don't forget the closing parenthesis..
```

In this example, the screenshot was saved in the same key as the tab's URI using [`localStorage.setItem`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/local-storage/info).
You can enumerate through the keys as follows:

```
for (var i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++) {
    var keyname = localStorage[i];            // Or localStorage.key(0);
    var thumb = localStorage.getItem(keyname);// <-- Retrieve the value
}
```

If you don't like the thumb, it can be removed using the `localStorage.removeItem` method:

```
var keyname = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';  // For example
localStorage.removeItem(keyname);
```

**Note**: `localStorage` is limited to 5MB. Consider using the asynchronous [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API for persisting data.