# Get the image file of chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to capture current page of Chrome in Chrome extension. Then I find

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(integer windowId, object options, function callback)
```

The callback function is like

```
function(string dataUrl) {...};
```

When I try to use this API, the dataUrl I get is like

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwME…OdiCJJMxdVYyueT/tGodJ0nTdBsks9Ogt7G0RmZYIAFRcnJwOw9B0AwBgAUUV9AZFeiiigD//Z...
```

But I want to use this image file location or save it to another location. So how can I achieve this?
Or Is there any other way to capture a web page screenshot and then save this page as a file in chrome extension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser/HTML Force download of image from src="data:image/jpeg;base64..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473932/browser-html-force-download-of-image-from-src-dataimage-jpegbase64)

Comment: `data:image/jpeg;base64,...` is a valid URL. If you do not want to download a file, what did you mean by "... then save this page as a file"?

Comment: I mean save this file to some specific location in extension. This should all be done in code.

Comment: Do you mean something like [How can I save a tab thumbnail to local storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036871/how-can-i-save-a-tab-thumbnail-to-local-storage/10040929#10040929)?

Comment: No, I want to save the image file to some location like "C:\temp".

Comment: That's not possible. The user has to select the target folder. Imagine what happens if a web page is allowed to write to any arbitrary directory on your file system...

Answer (score 1):

You can send the base64 encoded jpeg to a server running php to save the file.
*This example disregards security to simplify the example*

```
<?php
$screenshot = $_POST['screenshot'];
$screenshot = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $screenshot);
$screenshot = str_replace(' ', '+', $screenshot);
$data = base64_decode($screenshot);
$file = uniqid() . '.jpeg';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

You could then have the server return the reference to the image to download.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find a good answer to this online. This code will take a screenshot, then download the image to your computer:

In my `manifest.json`

```json
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
...
```

In `background.js`

```js
const download = (dataurl, filename) => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = dataurl;
    link.download = filename;
    link.click();
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(async (dataUrl) => {
        await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            func: download,
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            args: [dataUrl, 'test.png'],
        });
    });
});
```